# Syntax of Greplace

Tags: vim, replace

I want to change some words in several files using VIM. To do this, I found out about [Greplace](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1813), which appears to be made to do just that. However, in the [documentation](https://github.com/vim-scripts/greplace.vim/blob/master/doc/greplace.txt) there is no sample of the syntax of Greplace (there is a sample of Gsearch, but I need the replace function).

Say I want to change "foo" for "bar" in all ".asp" files, how could that be achieved with Greplace (or any other method). I do not care about confirmation (it's fine if it requires confirmation; it's also fine if it does not).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's trivial to do without a dedicated plugin.

```
$ vim *.asp
:bufdo %s/foo/bar/ge | update
:q
```

- `:bufdo` runs the following commands on all buffers.
- `%s/foo/bar/ge` replaces foo with bar on all lines and all occurrences in each line.  The `e` flag makes sure `:s` doesn't emit an error if it doesn't find foo, since foo may not exist in all the files.
- `|` is Vim's way of separating multiple commands to run.  See `:help :bar`
- `update` saves the file back to disk, only if any changes were actually made.

Comment: slick. but wont work with unopened buffers. ie. "do this for all files in directory"

Comment: @OrenMazor, sure, but there aren't any unopened buffers in my example.

Comment: I was definitely thinking out loud for my usecase :)